# Alert from timer in background mode

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I have not really done much with background mode before and I have not used push notifications before.

What am trying to achieve is to give the user a warning they are going to be auto logged out 5 minutes before it happens and give them a chance to refresh their token.

It works fine when the app is active in the foreground. I pop up an alert and get them to click “ok” otherwise after 5 mins it logs out.

I have added

```
@ionic-native/background-mode
```

to my project and enabled background mode but I am not sure how to get the app to alert the user.

**Is there a way to do this? Or can I only run "non UI" tasks from the background**

Could I use a push notification locally from the app to notify the user rather than an alert or do push notifications only work from a server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used local notifications:

https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/local-notifications

```
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
const { LocalNotifications } = Plugins;

LocalNotifications.schedule({
      notifications: [
        {
          title: 'Title',
          body: 'Body',
          id: 1,
          schedule: { at: new Date(Date.now() + 5000) },
          sound: null,
          attachments: null,
          actionTypeId: '',
          extra: null
        }
      ]
    });
```